# Regex in ms word to replace last octet?

Tags: regex, ms-word

I'm using this

> ([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})(.[0-9]{1,3})

to replace `122.22.12.44` with `122.12.12.11`.
In replace section I write `\1\211`.
So far its not working it just replaces as `122.12.12.4411`

Any help I'm using ms word replace function.

Comment: PERFECT it worked i just had to add \1.11 so it doesn't remove the dot :)

Comment: @anishsane Please write it as an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as answer.

When you are using regex

```
([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})(.[0-9]{1,3})
```

to match, the first bracked matches the first three octets & the seconds bracket matches the last octet.

Since you want to replace the last octet, you should keep the first 3 octets as they are (use `\1`) & append the replacement octet after that.

Thus, your replacement string should be `\1.11`.

Currently is it set to `\1\211` Thus it match all the four octets & appends 44 after it, giving you result as `122.12.12.4411`.